# Porque la localización en un emulador IOS me da las coordenadas de san francisco?

Tags: ios, ionic, macos, geolocalización, leaflet

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en ionic y a la hora de ejecutar el proyecto en el emulador IOS con el comando:

```
ionic cordova run ios --emulator -lc
```

El proyecto corre de maravilla pero cuando quiero usar la localización y cargar un mapa, el marcador me dice que se encuentra en san francisco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es porque el emulador de iOS esta configurado por *default* con esas coordenadas pero tú la puedes cambiar como se muestra en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]